# How to use blender change material color with python

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, color

I have a model about blender,there is a object （name's car_AudiA8） with multi-material，I want to copy a new object from the object ("car_AudiA8"),then change new object's color and old object's color is not affected,my method is :

`obj = bpy.data.objects["car_AudiA8"]
mesh = obj.data
new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("car_AudiA8", mesh)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(new_obj)
bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(object = True, obdata = True, material=True,texture = True )
for slot in bpy.data.objects[new_obj.name].material_slots:
    if (slot.name.startswith("carpaint.Black")):
        bpy.data.materials[slot.name].diffuse_color = (1,0,0)`

but when the method doesn't work,I don't know reason. when render the object , car's color doesn't change.

[image]

Comment: Script works fine, but maybe you use cycles?

Comment: how  do it I should ?

Comment: provide a screenshot, please

Comment: I render model with python . I use the code --"bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True ) "

Comment: Ok, you have cycles renderer, but `diffuse_color` is internal renderer value. So you mast recreate you materials to internal, or change color in nodes